# "No suitable constructor found for type" and the type exists and has a default constructor

Tags: java, tomcat, jaxb, jersey

I am receiving this message in a new jersey 1.19.4 app that I am building:

```
No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<com.objex.idms.idd.types.IDDModule>]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5a5e4ec1; line: 1, column: 2]
```

After much searching I have seen many posts that indicate this can be caused by a missing default constructor. However that doesn't seem to the the case here.  Note I have tried this implementing "Serializable" with the same result.  I am sure it's something simple but am just missing it.

Here is the class in question, any thoughts you might have would be appreciated.

```
package com.objex.idms.idd.types;

// import java.io.Serializable;

public class IDDModule {
    /**
     * 
     */
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1897236478938746827L;

    private String DictName;
    private String DictNode;
    private String Name;
    private String Version;
    private String Language;
    private String ModuleMetadata;
    private String ModuleSource;
    private String Message;

    public IDDModule() {
    }   
    /**
     * @param dictName the dictName to set
     */
    public void setDictName(String DictName) {
        this.DictName = DictName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the dictName
     */
    public String getDictName() {
        return DictName;
    }
    /**
     * @param DictNode the dictNode to set
     */
    public void setDictNode(String DictNode) {
        this.DictNode = DictNode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the dictNode
     */
    public String getDictNode() {
        return DictNode;
    }
    /**
     * @param language the language to set
     */
    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.Language = language;
    }
    /**
     * @return the language
     */
    public String getLanguage() {
        return Language;
    }
    /**
     * @param Message the message to set
     */
    public void setMessage(String Message) {
        this.Message = Message;
    }
    /**
     * @return the message
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }
    /**
     * @param ModuleMetadata the moduleMetadata to set
     */
    public void setModuleMetadata(String ModuleMetadata) {
        this.ModuleMetadata = ModuleMetadata;
    }
    /**
     * @return the ModuleMetadata
     */
    public String getModuleMetadata() {
        return ModuleMetadata;
    }
    /**
     * @param ModuleSource the moduleSource to set
     */
    public void setModuleSource(String ModuleSource) {
        this.ModuleSource = ModuleSource;
    }
    /**
     * @return the moduleSource
     */
    public String getModuleSource() {
        return ModuleSource;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    /**
     * @param version the version to set
     */
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.Version = version;
    }
    /**
     * @return the version
     */
    public String getVersion() {
        return Version;
    }
}
```

Comment: You use the .NET naming convention for variables.  Java assumes lower case first characters for member names.  You might be breaking the Java Bean conventions by doing so.  You might have thrwarted the JSON library if it depends too heavily on reflection.

Comment: Appreciate the comment but it doesn't explain the complaint regarding the constructor.  Are you talking about using "public void setP(int,T)" for the setters?  None of the Jersey examples I have seen are doing that.